# How to get unpinned explorer.exe back to taskbar?

Tags: windows-8

This is not a big problem actually. my brother unpinned original explorer.exe from taskbar. and i can't find a way to get it back. maybe some of you would help me

Answer (score 1):

To repin the explorer to the task bar,

please follow the below steps,

Click on the start menu and then type explorer in the search program and files column.

Now explorer is listed,please  right click on it and then choose the option pin to the taskbar.Now you can see the explorer pin to the task bar.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when this happens is to copy from the START menu the specific program shortcut to the desktop, in this case windows explorer.  It is located in the accessories sub-menu.

Then move the icon to the taskbar and PIN It.

You can then remove the desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Press Windows-Key and E together will start the Explorer, then you can pin its icon onto task bar again.